# How to solve: $y'''(t)=2(1-y'(t))t$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve following diferential equations
$$y'''(t)=2(1-y'(t))t$$
I tried many tehniques without any success. I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing $u(t) = 1 - y'(t)$, then $u'' = -y'''$ and hence the ODE can be rewritten

$$u'' + 2tu = 0$$

This equation has solutions in terms of Airy functions. And so $y$ will be integrals of those expressions.

Comment: (+1) They are really interesting functions since the are entire functions of the complex plane with non-integer order $\alpha=\frac{3}{2}$.